# Laravel collection get columns to array

Tags: php, laravel

I have collection:

```
$categories = $post->categories;
```

I get this:

```
#items: array:1 [▼
   0 => Category {#999 ▶}
   1 => Category {#999 ▶}
]
```

I need get from category `id`.

I try this:

```
$categories = array_column('id', $post->categories);
```

But with collections `array_column` not working. How I can do this?

Comment: how about `$categories = array_column($post->categories,'id');`? you just misplaced the arguments

Answer (score 12):

There are already some good answers.

An alternative is:

```
$category_ids = $post->categories->pluck('id');
```

Comment: This answer should be set as solved!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get any property from a collection, use `map` higher order message.

example.

```
$category_ids = $post->categories->map->id;
```

that's it.

Answer (score 1):

First convert your  collection to array. You can use [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-toarray) of eloquent as below.

```
$categories = $post->categories()->get()->toArray();
```

And this

```
$categories = array_column('id', $post->categories);
```

Should be

```
$categories = array_column($post->categories, 'id');
```

Your new code should look like:

```
$categories = $post->categories()->get()->toArray();

$categories = array_column($categories, 'id');
```

Ref: [array_column](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_column.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I know that was asked 11 years ago but having same question and here the solution that works in laravel 10.x:

```
$categories->groupBy('category_id')
```

It will returns:

```
[
  112 => [Category],
  420 => [Category],
  ...
  n => [Category]
]
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-groupby